# Nonlinear system general representation

Tags: control, control-system, non-linear

I am fairly new with non linear systems. I understand that a general representation of a nonlinear system is:
$$
\dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)\cdot u
$$

where \$x\$ is the state variable, and \$u\$ the input. My question is rather general: can \$ f(x)\$ be just a constant? Example: would it be possible to have:

$$
\dot{x} = 3 + 2x\cdot u
$$

Thank you very much for your help.

Lello

Comment: Yeah that's fine, as long as you can't separate what depends on state and what depends on input it's still non-linear

Comment: That is not a general representation of a nonlinear system. It is the general representation of a finite-dimensional dynamical system whose dynamics are (possibly) nonlinear in state and linear in input.